# can we say that $|x|=|G:C_{G}(x)|$???

Tags: group-theory

I am very confused about this:

we know that $|x|=|x^{g}|$, and the cardinal  of $x^{g}=|G:C_{G}(x)|$ where $C_{G}(x)$ is the centralizer of $x$.

Can we always say that:

$|x|=|G:C_{G}(x)|=|G/C_{G}(x)|$ and $\langle x \rangle \cong G/C_{G}(x)$  ????

Comment: Take $G=S_3$, and $x=(12)$. Find $|x|$ and $|G\colon C_G(x)|$.

Comment: What if $G$ is abelian?

Comment: @pGroups i do not know yet what $S_{3}$ is

Comment: @Meriem: $S_3$ is the set of bijections from a set with $3$ elements to itself.  It forms a group with operation given by function composition. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group

Comment: @NajibIdrissi if $G$ is abelian then $G=C_{G}(G)$  and then??

Comment: @Meriem: If $G$ is abelian, what is $x^g$?

Comment: @PhilipHoskins it is $x$

Comment: Right, so the statement you wrote would imply what about $\vert x \vert$?

Comment: Well don't you see a contradiction here?

Comment: I can see it now thank you very much

Comment: I just want to add that now, I can see  where my mistake is. I said that $|x|=|x^{g}|$ but $x^{g}$ is an element of the set $\{x^{g} |g\in G\}$ which its cardinal ( the whole set) is equal to $|G:C_{G}(x)|$, this last is cleary defferent of $|x^{g}|$. Thanks all helpers